# TBB vs. Homegrown Workqueue

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, parallel-processing, tbb

I know `TBB` (Thread Building Blocks) claim to have a sophisticated engine, but from the algorithmic point of view:

If we had (say on Linux) a workqueue that has `N` working-threads (POSIX threads, `N` is the number of cores) and a mutex-synchronized queue of tasks, each working thread then taking a task from the queue when idle, also some synchronization calls, what else could `TBB` offer, not counting nice `C++` syntax? I don't see a better algorithm than greedy assignment of tasks to cores.

Comment: "I don't see a better algorithm than greedy assignment of tasks to cores." - definitely use a library

Comment: Please, could you sketch some algorithms that can do better?

Comment: TBB appears to have documentation. You could start [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2010/05/04/tbb-30-new-today-version-of-intel-threading-building-blocks/) or [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2010/05/13/tbb-30-task-scheduler-improves-composability-of-tbb-based-solutions-part-1/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As somebody who has developed their own work-stealing scheduler, I can say the following:

- *Don’t* write your own scheduler (and a work-queue counts here).
- You’ll either do it inefficiently, or you’ll do it wrong.

In fact, it’s not that hard to write a correct scheduler. Unfortunately, it *is* hard if you want to do it efficiently. An efficient scheduler effectively precludes the use of locks (except perhaps in very specific, well-specified situations) and lock-free cross-thread communication is a world of pain.

As an anecdote, I actually implemented one scheduler where I essentially had to *copy* the existing algorithm into code and I still managed to introduce almost any race condition imaginable into the code. Debugging this code was a mixture of

- writing *huge*, convoluted test cases (just to pick up the occasional failure which only occurred in < 1% of the runs),
- spending hours on end just *staring* at the code, trying to figure out the error by applying logic
- tracing each single line in the debugger (which would crash without stack trace once an error occurred), keeping track of the state of *all* variables in *all* threads manually just to be sure that the actual state of the program matched the expected state
- reducing the code several times essentially down to zero and rebuilding, commenting out single lines or pairs of lines to see the effect (*huge* combinatorial space), and
- running against walls, head first.

Comment: I suggest you heart this recommendation. Fully. No discussion. No really.

Comment: +1 Great piece. I just watched the Google tech talk with Hans Boehm, which added extra weight to just how hard getting concurrency right can be (e.g. he said that for the longest time (and maybe to this day) it was unclear whether it is actually *possible* to implement Java correctly).

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing the precise implementation of TBB, I cannot say what exactly it offers, but since you said "what *could* it offer"...

Among others,

- It could offer lockfree queueing and unqueueing instead of one syscall and context switch per task. This is harder to implement than it sounds.
- It could, in addition, offer blocking of worker threads if the queue is empty. This again, is harder to implement than it sounds.
- It could offer work stealing.
- It could offer LIFO task-to-thread assignment in the same way Windows completion ports work (improving cache efficiency).
- It could be bug-free. This, again, is something harder to implement than you think.